# IBM MQ - Redistributable Managed File Transfer client "runmqsc" fails

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I want to install a re-distributable managed file transfer agent in a Linux machine 
which in turn will transfer files to a windows machine. My issue is, do I need to install the 
IBM MQ in the machine which the re-distributable client is installed, because when I run 
the command in the client

`runmqsc MFTU < RDSAGTLIN_create.mqsc > mftu.out`

to create the required object for the redistributable client, (MFTU is the Queue manager name and RDSAGTLIN is the re-distributable client agent name), the below error pops up.

`[root@mqlocalhost RDSAGTLIN]# runmqsc MFTU < RDSAGTLIN_create.mqsc > mftu.out
 bash: runmqsc: command not found...`

I understand `runmqsc` is a IBM MQ command, my question is do I have to install the IBM MQ 
in the client also to setup the re-distributable file transfer agent?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Regards,

Yasothar

Comment: No, you don't need to install IBM MQ on the machine where you want to run an agent that uses MFT Redistributable Package. But you need to have MQ installed, configured and running for use with MFT somewhere. With MFT Redistributable, runmqsc is not shipped. You need to run "runmqsc MFTU < RDSAGTLIN_create.mqsc " on a machine where agent queue manager is running.

Comment: Very much understood Shashi,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runmqsc` should be delivered in an MQ Client only installation, so you don't need a full IBM MQ installation if you only need to add `runmqsc`. You will need a 'C' client if you are trying to use `runmqsc` against a queue manager on a different machine. e.g. `runmqsc -c`

However, your question appears to be trying to use `runmqsc` against a queue manager on the same machine - is this the case? If so your problem might simply be that you have not found `runmqsc` in your path. Have you used the `setmqenv` command to set up your environment?

If this is not the case and the queue manager MFTU is on a different machine then it might be as easy to run the `runmqsc` command directly on that machine? `runmqsc` will be available there because the full queue manager installation will be there.

Comment: Thank u so much Morag, the answer was really helpful. Thank u for the time.

Comment: Hi Morag, do have any good reference on installing IBM MQ client in a Linux environment (aprat from IBM documentaion), will be pleased if you can point one.

Comment: I always use the IBM documentation for installation tasks. It's the one part of Knowledge Center that is complete in my view.